# How to delete a particular variable from a configuration created by a custom module

Tags: 8, configuration

I have created a custom module and a configuration say 'abc_settings'. This configuration creates a variable for each vocabulary present on the site like vocab1_options, vocab2_options, vocab3_options etc.
I want to delete 'vocab1_options' when vocabulary 1 (vocab1) will be deleted. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Deleting a config *key*:**

Updating per Berdirs comment, deleting/clearing a key *within* a config object, not deleting the entire config object:

```
Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('abc_settings')->clear($entity->id() . '_options')->save();
```

**Deleting config *objects*:**

I did this within TVI module, anytime a term or vocab is deleted:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_delete().
 * Remove TVI settings when vocabularies are deleted.
 * @param EntityInterface $entity
 */
function tvi_taxonomy_vocabulary_delete(EntityInterface $entity) {
  Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('tvi.taxonomy_vocabulary.' . $entity->id())->delete();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_taxonomy_term_delete().
 * Remove TVI settings when terms are deleted.
 * @param EntityInterface $entity
 */
function tvi_taxonomy_term_delete(EntityInterface $entity) {
  Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('tvi.taxonomy_term.' . $entity->id())->delete();
}
```

Of course, you would pass your own config name to getEditable(), and the hook names need to have your module name and not *tvi*.

This will delete any config matching that name when a term or vocab is deleted.

I haven't taken the step yet in my own code, but you could go further and implement a method that before a vocabularly entity is deleted, get all of its children, loop and delete config, then delete the vocab and its config.

Example:

```
Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable($entity->id() . '_options')->delete();
```

Comment: Is that really what was asked? This deletes whole configuration objects, I understood the question as deleting keys in a configuration object. For that, you can use ->clear('some_key')->save().

Comment: From the names I inferred them as a config object per vocab. I see now..